# restore dropdown selection after refresh local storage

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save an options tag value to local storage. After saving its value to local storage I would like to be able to set the options tag to the option the user selected. I have tried the follow, but I am only able to save the value. I have trouble changing the select tag to the users selected value.

```
<select name="fruit" id="fruit">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Guava</option>
    <option value="3">Mango</option>
    <option value="4">Grapes</option>
</select>

document.getElementById("fruit").onchange = function() {
 localStorage.setItem('fruit', document.getElementById("fruit").value);
}

if (localStorage.getItem('fruit') === "Guava") {
 document.getElementById("fruit").setAttribute('Selected', 'Guava');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your option values are integers, in this case, I would check against the *value* of the option, not the textual contents of the option element.

Here's a solution that works if you have incremental numerical option values, starting from zero:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyxut/6/)

HTML:

```
<select name="fruit" id="fruit">
    <option value="0">Apple</option>
    <option value="1">Guava</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
    <option value="3">Grapes</option>
</select>
```

And your JS would be:

```
document.getElementById("fruit").onchange = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('fruit', document.getElementById("fruit").value);
}

if (localStorage.getItem('fruit')) {
    document.getElementById("fruit").options[localStorage.getItem('fruit')].selected = true;
}​
```

Comment: demo works great but when i copy paste it into my project i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined "

Comment: You should add some checks for the localStorage value. For example, if your localStorage has the value of 4, you would get that kind of an error because there is no option with the index 4 in this code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Its because your values and text are different for your select options.
Try:

```
 <select name="fruit" id="fruit">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Guava">Guava</option>
    <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="Grapes">Grapes</option>
</select>

    document.getElementById("fruit").onchange = function() {
     localStorage['fruit'] = document.getElementById("fruit").value;
    }
    window.onload= function(){
        if(localStorage['fruit'])
            document.getElementById("fruit").value = localStorage['fruit'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are storing the **value** of the selection in local storage, but then trying to use the option **text** to compare against.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding how your application is working.

Anyway, this snippet should get your value selected properly (for the Guava fruit):

```
$("#fruit option[value='2']").attr("selected","selected");
```

If you must set the options tag by the text of the option (Guava):

```
$("#fruit option").each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == "Guava")
    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
});
```