# Store input values in session variable and get them back (PHP related)

Tags: php, session

I have a form in which there are 10 fields, some of them are drop downs. Halfway through there is one drop down list which is mandatory and next to it is a link for adding new item to this drop down. Add new link goes to another form where entry can be made and that entry will be reflected in the drop down. Now what I want to do is when the form comes back to the original form the values in fields prior to this drop down must be retained. Also remember that the link is just an a element so data is not getting posted so the values cannot be taken into session without pressing submit button. I already tried with session but its not working because as I said without pressing button values are not posted so no question of getting them in session. Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.
My problem is something like what happens on social networking sites. When you start filling your profile somewhere in between you are asked to upload your image. That link takes you to another page where after loading your photo you come back to the original form and all values are still retained. The form is still not complete and not submitted but already filled values are there.
Here is my code for that drop down list but I think code is not of much help. The scenario is important in this case:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Dealer Name
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['new_id']))
        {


    $new_id = $_GET['new_id'];
    ?>
        <select class="field" name="dealer">
            <option>--Select--</option>
            <?php
            $result = "SELECT Name, id FROM dealer ORDER BY Name ASC";
            $data5 = mysqli_query($link, $result);
            while ($rec5 = mysqli_fetch_array($data5))
            {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rec5['id']; ?>" <?php if($rec5['id'] == $new_id) { echo 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $rec5['Name']; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
        <select class="field" name="dealer">
            <option>--Select--</option>
            <?php
            $result = "SELECT Name, id from dealer ORDER BY Name ASC";
            $data5 = mysqli_query($link, $result);
            while ($rec5 = mysqli_fetch_array($data5)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rec5['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rec5['Name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</td>
<td>
    <div style="width:68px;">
        <a href="dealer_add.php&amp;action=add_new_dealer" class="button alignright" style="text-decoration:none;">
            Add New
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
<td></td>
```

@Ashish, I'm not sending any value through drop down. There is a link next to it for this.

Comment: Please provide some sample code. This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886793/drop-down-menu-to-remember-selection-and-redirect-user

Comment: as u r linking page from dropdown items..why dont u try to send parameter by URL and retrive that parameter on other page with $_GET

Comment: Either don’t reload the original form (and do the adding of new options purely client-side with JS) – or submit it, so that you have the form values before “destroying” the form by reloading it after new option is added.