# Remember selection and redirect user to a visited subdomain

Tags: javascript, redirect, subdomain

When a user visits example.com, he is presented with many other sub-domains(cities) to choose from. I would like to let a user selects or types(on address bar) say a.example.com, on his next visit to example.com he should be re-directed to a.example.com. When he visit b.example.com and he should be re-directed to b.example.com.

I found this code [Drop down menu to remember selection and redirect user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886793/drop-down-menu-to-remember-selection-and-redirect-user) and it is close to what I need. I would like to remove the drop down menu(form) and replace with a single page which listed with all the cities. I have tested the code below and the redirection is not accurate. I need more robust and fast script. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (localStorage && localStorage.country) {
    location = localStorage.country;    
}

function formChanged(form) {
    var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
    if (val !== 'non-value') {
      if (localStorage) {
        localStorage.country = val;
      }
      location = val;
    }
}
</script>

<FORM NAME="form1">
  <select onchange="formChanged(this);" NAME="country" SIZE="1">
    <OPTION VALUE="non-value">Select Country
    <OPTION VALUE="chile">Chile
    <OPTION VALUE="colombia">Colombia
    <OPTION VALUE="bolivia">Bolivia
  </select>
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is when you use cookies.

```
function setSelection(elem){
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 99999); // A really not time, AKA never
  var c_value=escape(elem.value) + exdate.toUTCString();
  document.cookie="selection=" + c_value;
}
```

Reference here to get the value, and then you can work with it. As you'll see, the above is pretty much a copy paste from the page. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: What do you mean any solution?

Comment: Well, use what I gave you above, and see if you can write the second half. If you get stuck, report back with code. Assuming you can follow instructions though, you should find it rather simple.

Comment: I am not sure where to start. Can you please write the second half? Thank you.

Comment: I will fix the second half, but you have to give it a shot first. If you want somebody to write your code for you, then you'll have to pay them. Not trying to be mean, but trial and error is how you learn.