# Drop down menu to remember selection and redirect user with ability to change the selected country

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, redirect, local-storage

[Following this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886793/drop-down-menu-to-remember-selection-and-redirect-user) - But this question is providing only solution for one time use.

My problem is that when I have dropdown menu and I select some city from select dropdown I am redirected to city page and my selection is saved to local storage so every time I visit website again I'm redirected to the city I've chosen from my first website visit. This is fine.

What do I need is to put this select menu on every page of the website and I need ability to change it anytime I want. So when I'm currently in New York but tomorrow I will be in LA and I want to order some food I just change the city in select menu and It will set a new primary website homepage redirect to LA URL address.

I have tried to put the dropdown for into every page - to header but when I have put it there I m stuck at redirect loop, so when I choose a New York city at homepage at my first time visit and dropdown is on page of New York (in header for example) it keeps redirecting me from New York to New York with infinite redirect loop and this is what I need to eliminate.

My code is here. Any ideas please? Providing a code edit would be great because I'm newbie in JavaScript and it takes me ages to move with this problem. Thank you very much!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (localStorage && localStorage.country) {
    location = localStorage.country;    
}

function formChanged(form) {
    var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
    if (val !== 'non-value') {
      if (localStorage) {
        localStorage.country = val;
      }
      location = val;
    }
}
</script>

<FORM NAME="form1">
<select onchange="formChanged(this);" NAME="country" SIZE="1">
<OPTION VALUE="non-value">Select delivery city
<OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/cadca/">New York
<OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/brno/">Los Angeles
<OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/bratislava/">Tokyo
</select>
</FORM>
```

UPDATE - This is working fine, but this script is not showing actual selected option when I'm at the current page url. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.href.indexOf(localStorage.country) == -1){
location.href = localStorage.country
}

function formChanged(form) {
var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
if (val !== 'non-value') {
if (localStorage) {
localStorage.country = val;
}

if (!location.href.indexOf(val)) {    
location = val;
   }
  }
 }

 </script>

 <FORM NAME="form1">
 <select id="saleTerm" onchange="formChanged(this); location = 
 this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" NAME="country" SIZE="1">
 <OPTION VALUE="non-value">Select delivery city
 <OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/cadca/">Čadca
 <OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/brno/">Brno
 <OPTION id="bratislava" VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/bratislava/">Bratislava
 </select>
 </FORM>
```

Comment: Instead of `location = localStorage.country;` I would try: `if(location.href != localStorage.country){location.href = localStorage.country}`

Comment: Hello @imvain2 thank you for your response. This solution keeps me in redirect loop aswell. :/ I have replaced the first 3 lines under <script> tag as you mentioned in your comment but it did not help.

Comment: @imvain2 see my question edit to see how Ive edited the code.

Comment: Ok try this: `if(location.href.indexOf(localStorage.country) == -1){`

Comment: @imvain2 this works great. Thank you! But now when I select any other city from dropdown for example LA, it does not redirect me after select and I have to refresh the New York page manualy to see the selected dropdown city and after refresh it shows me LA. So it has disable the automatic redirection from select.

Comment: @imvain2 updated code in question

Comment: @imvain2 put your solution to answer please so I could mark it as the working answer. Please coud you please take a look at my code in UPDATE section? It would be great if form displays current selected term. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is bellow. All credits are for @imvain2 . Thank you very much. If you could post your answer here so I could mark it as solution.

Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.href.indexOf(localStorage.country) == -1){
location.href = localStorage.country
}

function formChanged(form) {
var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
if (val !== 'non-value') {
if (localStorage) {
localStorage.country = val;
}

if (!location.href.indexOf(val)) {    
location = val;
  }
 }
}

</script>

<FORM NAME="form1">
<select id="saleTerm" onchange="formChanged(this); location = 
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" NAME="country" SIZE="1">
<OPTION VALUE="non-value">Select delivery city
<OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/cadca/">Čadca
<OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/brno/">Brno
<OPTION id="bratislava" VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/bratislava/">Bratislava
</select>
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inplace of

```
!location.href.indexOf(val)
```

write

```
location.href.indexOf(val) === -1
```