# JQuery Options added from js but selected value is not working

Tags: jquery

I am adding the options of a select item dynamically.

I added under

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

the following code

```
$options = '<option name="en" value="en" SELECTED>English</option><option name="de" value="de">German</option>';

$("#select_language").html($options);
```

when I refresh the page, the options can can be seen in my drop down menu. The problem is, the selected value is not comming as default value. What should I do?

Comment: You want the selected value to persist? If so, you would need to use a cookie or localStorage.

Comment: I am the current value in a localStorage variable. When the user opens the page, I only want to show the current value (from localstorage) as the selected value.

Comment: Works for me? http://jsfiddle.net/q43rk/

Comment: Seems to work in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/c6Zj9/ S.B beat me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873822/restore-dropdown-selection-after-refresh-local-storage

Comment: @MrHunter Haha, beat by 2 seconds. ;)

Comment: one of you put that fiddle in an answer

Comment: So what is the question indeed???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. jQueryMobile was expecting to refresh the select menu with

> $("#select_language").selectmenu("refresh",true);

the final working code is as bellow.

```
 var $options = '<option name="en" value="en"
 selected="selected">English</option><option name="de"
 value="de">German</option>';

 $("#select_language").append($options);

 if($('#select_language option:selected').length > 0 ) {


var selected = $('#select_language').val();
     alert(selected); 

} else {


     alert('nothing selected'); 
}

 $("#select_language").selectmenu("refresh",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/stG89/1/

```
if($('#select_language option').prop('selected')) {
    var selected = $('#select_language').val(); 
    console.log(selected); // should log 'en' in this case
} else {
    console.log('nothing selected');
}
```

Comment: Hi it returns "en" in the console. BUt on the page, I can not see the value as selected. but as I said the options are there

Comment: I am using the NativeDroid template. can this be something related it? CSS etc?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot see the value"? Are you trying to examine the source? If so, you need to use something (like Firebug) that reflect the updated DOM. Your actual HTML source will not change.