# Not able to set the selected index in html using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my Javascript:

```
    var productId=this.dataset.product
    var action=this.dataset.action
    var a = document.getElementById(productId);
    var size = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
    var l = toString(document.getElementById(productId).selectedIndex);
    a.selectedIndex=l;
    updateUserOrder(productId, action, size)
```

In this I am able to get the productId , action , a , size , l correctly but I am not able to set the index selected thereafter. When a user on my site clicks on add button the product is added to cart with the correct size and all and also the page refreshes . But as tried in my code the selected option does not change as I want it to and remains the default (index=0).

This is my html for reference:

```
<select class="selection-2 border" data-product={{product.id}}
               style="border: cadetblue;" name="size" id="{{product.id}}">
              
                <option value="S" id="S">S</option>
                <option value="M" id="M">M</option>
                <option value="L" id="L">L</option>
              
              </select>
```

My problem summed up is that for example a user chooses  an option which is at second index then after the page refreshes(as my code executes) the select box should show default option as the option with second index which is currently not happening.

Comment: Can you replace the template code with the resulting `<select>` and turn this into a runnable code snippet to demonstrate?

Comment: @David I have set the options to what it looks when the code is executed

Comment: DOM changes don't persist after the page is refreshed. If you want to remember their selection between refreshes, put it in `localStorage` and then reassign it when the page reloads.

Comment: Is there a reason why in your loop that fills in the select that you just don't add an `if` statement that adds `selected` to the correct option?

Comment: @Barmar Can you please tell how does that work. I am new at this

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873822/restore-dropdown-selection-after-refresh-local-storage

Comment: @Barmar I will look upto it but isnt there any other way other than yours like the selected attribute .

Comment: @VATSALJAIN, if you are storing the shopping cart somehow, that means the information is already in a manner that is available across pages. So in your code that is used to pull back the shopping cart, just find that size in the cart, and in the loop that shows the select options, have an if statement that says if the stored size is the same add `selected` to that option.

Comment: @Barmar can you somehow tell how would localstorage be used in my code

Comment: @imvain2 as I am iterating over options in my actual code then how do I set selected in options

Comment: @VATSALJAIN, I don't know the syntax/abilities of the templating that you are using nor the variable structure but this is a pseudocode you can use as a guide:

`{% for t in product.size.all %}
     if({{t}} == product.size){
  selected = "selected"
  }
  else{
  selected = ""
  }
 <option {{selected}} value="{{t}}" id="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: @imvain2 and this product.size refers to the size of the product in cart. right?

Comment: @VATSALJAIN correct. I wasn't sure on your variables but I wanted the name to be something you would recognize

Comment: @imvain2 This is not working. Are you sure that the syntax of if else is correct to be used in html or there should be {%  ....  %}

Comment: @VATSALJAIN, I don't know the syntax, that is why the very beginning of that comment says that I don't. I was giving you an idea ie pseudocode to use as a guide to assist you in doing it.

Comment: @imvain2 Ok so is there any alternative option other than to use rendered data? Is using localstorage good and if yes can you tell me how to implement it here.It would be grateful of you.